# display alias password from keystore certificate

Tags: java, security

I use the below code to display alias name associated with my keystore certificate and it works fine , now **how can I display alias passowrd? Is there any method for this.**

```
public class keyaliasfinder {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        FileInputStream is = null;
        try {

            File file = new File("c:\\my_keystore");
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            String password = "FnvUKHdr6b4343dfdf";
            keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());

            PrivateKey p=new PrivateKey() {

                @Override
                public String getFormat() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getEncoded() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public String getAlgorithm() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }
            };


            Enumeration enumeration = keystore.aliases();
            while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                String alias = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
                System.out.println("alias name: " + alias);
                Certificate certificate = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
                System.out.println(certificate.toString());

            }

        } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(null != is)
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The password has to be provided for reading a private key from a key store. You have to know it. It is not stored in the key store.

Comment: @Robert but where do I mention this password are you talking about keystore password that is already there.

Comment: @Robert Of course it's stored in the KeyStore. But of course there isn't an API to retrieve it. Otherwise the KeyStore API would be insecure.

Comment: @EJP So as of now it is impossible to retrieve the password back ?

Comment: That is the purpose of a key store - store keys securely so that only persons who know the password can use the keys.

Comment: @Robert what if that person is not available or the password is lost somewhere by mistake.

Comment: @parteek You can guess passwords, use password lists or simply perform brute force attacks on the key store. But finding a password this way can take hours to thousands of years computing power.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused on your question. If you are trying to retrieve the alias password back, the password doesn't exist as clear text password. The password is used to generate an encryption key through password based derivation function and the key is used to protect your private key. But if you looking for an API to pass your alias password, once you load the keystore with keystore password (that's what you did), you can pass the alias password as follow.

```
Key privateKey = keystore.getKey(String alias, char[] aliasPassword)
```

or

```
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(aliasPassword);

//Get my private key
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)ks.getEntry("privateKeyAlias", protParam);
PrivateKey myPrivateKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
```

Comment: I am trying to retieve the alias password back , as you mentioned the same password that doesn't exist as clear text password is there any workaround or hack for it and what is the data required to get it back